# If statement [help] New to Java

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, jcreator

I am *REALLY* new at Java and I've tried to make a simple program to find the sides of a triangle (Side,side,side OR side,angle,side). But I when I run it in Jcreator it asks "Are you working with an SSS?[y/n]" when I type in "y" or "n" it always comes up with the same answer. I have no idea what it is.

**Here's the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CosineLaw {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean sss =true;

        System.out.println("Are you working with an SSS?[y/n]");
        char askingSSS =keyboard.next().charAt(0);  
        if(sss == true){
            System.out.println("Please enter the 3 sides:");
        }else if(sss == false){
            System.out.println("Please enter the 2 sides and 1 angle:");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sss is set to true on instantiation and never changed, it will always print `"Please enter the 3 sides:"`

Comment: This is because the value of the variable `sss` never changes.  You need something like `sss = (askingSSS=='y');`

Comment: If you're checking a `boolean` in an `if` statement, you don't need to compare it to `true`.  `(sss == true)` is identical to simply `(sss)`

Comment: You should accept @Rahul answer, it is the best way to say thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1) You never changed the boolean value of `sss`

```
boolean sss =true;
```

The value is always true and never changed.

2) You dont require the if statement in `else`.

```
if(sss == false)
```

The above statement inside else is not making any sense

You can better try something like this:

```
if(askingSSS == 'y')
else
```

Comment: Thank you >.< I'm really bad at this. Sorry if this was a dumb question.

Comment: @user2809115: You are welcome. Dont be sorry it happens as you already mentioned you are new to Java. P.S. Do accept this as an answer if that helped you! :)